# Correct way to document bubbled exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, documentation

Below is a simplified example of a setup I have. My issue is an exception is thrown at a low level which will then bubble up. However, classes at a higher level do not know what horrors await them when they use the lower level class functions. By this I mean developers will come along and use Class3.DoWork3() without any exception handling for the dreaded 'MyCustomException'.

Am I approaching this all wrong? I don't want to catch and throw the same exception multiple times (I have no need to do any kind of clean up for example in Class2).

```
public class Class1
{
    <exception cref="MyCustomException">description</exception>
    public void DoWork1()
    {
        throw new MyCustomException("I have failed you class1.");
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void DoWork2()
    {
        var classOne = new Class1();

        // Here I can see that DoWork1() will throw a 'MyCustomException'
        classOne.DoWork1();
    }
}

public class Class3
{
    public void DoWork3()
    {
        var classTwo = new Class2();

        // I can no longer see that Class2.DoWork2() will throw a 'MyCustomException'
        classTwo.DoWork2();
    }
}
```

In order to clear up some confusion which seems to have been generated in the comments I will put the two solutions which I am considering at present:

1. Tag DoWork2 with the same MyCustomException comment as Class1
2. Throw a different exception within DoWork2 and tag it with this
   new exception. This option seems the most robust as it would allow a
   more detailed log (e.g. where exactly the code fell over in it's
   execution path). This way does seem a little over the top for
   simplistic scenarios which is why I wonder if (1) is an acceptable
   solution to this problem?

Comment: I think this is too opinion-based for SO and it really depends on what you're doing.  You could always switch on the types of errors at the root of the program, etc.

Comment: You don't need to catch and throw the same exception simply add the doc where is needed.

Comment: So it's valid to add the same XML comment to DoWork2()?

Comment: You explicitly say custom exception but I'll say it anyway do you really need exceptions? It is a bad practice to regulate flow of your application by exception.

Comment: This is a very simplified example. I assure you we do need exceptions; we will not be regulating program flow with them but we will be handling (performing cleanup/rollback etc) and logging them.

Comment: @EricHotinger you say switch on the types of errors at the root of the program, care to expand on this? I do not need to catch base exception then switch on the type if that is what you are recommending.

Comment: @Beagle90 that is one thing that you could do. It depends on your situation.  Some people argue that catching/throwing numerous errors leads to needless bloat when you can minimize the error handling.

Comment: You assumption that the client code can catch and handle that exception implies that the client of your code knows *more* about the exceptional condition that you do.  Yes, that's going to require a *lot* of documentation, at least a manual.  The more likely scenario here is that your assumption is just wrong.  You don't know how to handle it, the client has no clue either.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't believe I mentioned client/server architecture anywhere in my question.

Comment: @HansPassant see my updated question in order to get a better idea of where I am going with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the major limitations with exception handling in .NET and Java is that there's no standardized means by which code can distinguish between an exception of some type which is thrown from a method for reasons that method expects, versus an exception of that same type which is thrown by a nested method, for reasons the outer method did not expect.  If the purpose of a method is to call some user-supplied delegate, the only ways I know of to reliably distinguish between exceptions which are thrown by the called delegate and those which occurred in the process of calling it are either to pass the method an identity token which it will include in any exceptions it throws directly, or else have the method as a matter of policy wrap exceptions that occur while invoking the user-supplied callback.  Neither method is terribly elegant.

Because there is no standardized way to identify exceptions which indicate that an operation failed "cleanly" without side-effects, from those which indicate that a more serious problem exists, I would suggest that code shouldn't rely upon "serious" exceptions to prevent "contagious" data corruption.  Instead, any time an exception might cause an object to be left in a corrupt state, the object should be *explicitly invalidated*, to prevent corrupt data from being read from it and copied elsewhere (possibly overwriting what would have been the only good copy).  In situations where the corrupted object isn't needed and stack unwinding would cause it to be invalidated, there is no problem.  In situations where the object that was invalidated turns out to be essential for system operation, the program should be forcibly shut down and invalidating the object will make that happen more reliably than would throwing a "serious" exception.

Unfortunately, neither C# nor VB.NET provides a very nice pattern for guarding objects in this fashion.  VB.NET has somewhat better exception-handling abilities than C#, and the correct pattern (taking action in a `finally` block based upon what exception was thrown, but without catching the exception) can be implemented, albeit awkwardly, in that language.  In C# the only way to find out what exception occurs within a `try` block is to catch and rethrow, an action which has some side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent interview with Anders Hejlsberg titled [*The Trouble with Checked Exceptions*](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html). (Anders led the team that designed the C# programming language.)

You are falling into the exception aggregation trap. You should probably not be asking "what exceptions could possibly be thrown by lower level systems?" The answer, in many cases, would be a list containing hundreds of unique exceptions.

Instead, you should ask yourself "how can I provide useful information to the developer?" You should document the exceptions that your code is explicitly throwing or, in rare cases, relevant exceptions that are very likely to occur and that the caller may be specifically interested in. The developer who calls your code can determine the necessity of handling those errors or passing that information along to the callers of their code - or simply doing nothing with it. Exceptions are exceptional, after all, and at a certain level it doesn't really matter which database error was thrown - the steps taken in response are the same (e.g. stabilize the environment if possible, write to the error log and terminate execution).